# Agrupar por día

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT  COUNT(pagos.idpago) AS Cantidad,    
    cuotas_inmuebles.decripcion as Cuotas, 
    concat(YEAR(pagos.fechadoc),LPAD(MONTH(pagos.fechadoc),3,'/0')) AS Fecha,
    DAY(pagos.fechadoc) AS Dia,
    CASE 
        WHEN DAY(pagos.fechadoc)<= '15' THEN '1'
        Else '2'


     END 
        As Quincena
FROM pagos JOIN cuotas_inmuebles 
        ON pagos.idcuota_inmueble= cuotas_inmuebles.idcuota_inmueble
GROUP BY Cuotas, DAY(pagos.fechadoc), Quincena  
ORDER BY Cuotas,
         Fecha,
         Quincena
```

Quiero que los dia de la fecha se agrupen para que me devuelva '1' si esta entre el 01 y 15 del mes y '2' si esta entre el 16 y 31 del mes, he intentado pero aun no lo logro realizar.

Comment: Estaria bueno saber cual es el error que recibis. por favor mira [ask] <--ACA

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con

```
SELECT IF(DAY(pagos.fechadoc) BETWEEN 1 AND 15,1,2) AS Quincena
```

para seleccionar la quincena en la que cae el pago, y el agrupamiento

Para realizar el agrupamiento por quincena debes realizar tu query como una subquery para poder agrupar sobre el campo agregado,

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT  COUNT(pagos.idpago) AS Cantidad,    
        cuotas_inmuebles.decripcion as Cuotas, 
        concat(YEAR(pagos.fechadoc),LPAD(MONTH(pagos.fechadoc),3,'/0')) AS Fecha, IF(DAY(pagos.fechadoc) BETWEEN 1 AND 15,1,2) AS Quincena
    FROM pagos JOIN cuotas_inmuebles 
            ON pagos.idcuota_inmueble= cuotas_inmuebles.idcuota_inmueble

    ) AS t 
GROUP BY Cuotas, Quincena 
ORDER BY Cuotas,Fecha, Quincena
```